# How do i Anchor tag to specific tab content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Tyring to FIgure out how do i implement anchor tag that will open up specific tab
*

```js
*THis is the javascript for navigation tab*

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
*CSS for the page and navigation tab*

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
*This is the HTML section*
**In this case..when i clicked the link "Tokyo", i would like it to open up the tokyo tab.It seemed wont work using normal Href linking**


   

 <h2>Tabs</h2>
    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

    <a href="#Tokyo">goes to tokyo tab content</a>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Tabs</h2>
    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

    <a href="javascript:document.querySelector('#tb').click()">goes to tokyo tab content</a>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="tb" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p id="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus auctor commodo. Duis condimentum massa mi, vitae finibus nisl cursus ac. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In quis ante tortor. Donec quis ornare turpis.
        Aliquam dignissim sem diam, at tristique leo blandit non. Vivamus neque nisl, dictum sit amet vulputate ac, congue et massa. Aenean a faucibus tellus, a interdum nisi. Aliquam non nisl sed metus pharetra facilisis. Maecenas eu dictum urna, ornare
        pharetra felis. Nunc maximus mauris in sem cursus vehicula.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, the code works and thankyou very much! but how do i make it scroll down to view it contents when clicked that Href link..thanks!